# Why is there a difference in the orientation of my imagined body vs. my physical body?

Tags: neuroscience, perception

*My Personal Experience*

When I visualise a specific aspect of my body, the inner mental image *does not seem to be aligned* with my actual physical form in space.

What I mean by this is:

Say I identify a pain in my right ankle, and in my imagination I conjure a mental picture of my ankle to help me pinpoint the exact location of the pain ...

**... in my mind, the orientation of my body in the mental picture seems to be slightly forward of my actual physical body, and slightly turned or rotated towards the right.**

This is a two part question:

*Firstly:*

- Do other people share this experience ?

*Secondly*

- Is there any accepted explanation for the effect ?

My best guess is that it could be related to the lateralization of eye movements accompanying brain activity during different cognitive tasks.

http://www.nlpu.com/Articles/artic14.htm

> In 1977 Robert Dilts conducted a study, at the Langley Porter
>   Neuropsychiatric Institute in San Francisco, attempting to correlate
>   eye movements to particular cognitive and neurophysiological
>   processes. Dilts used electrodes to track both the eye movements and
>   brain wave characteristics of subjects who were asked questions
>   related to using the various senses of sight, hearing and feeling for
>   tasks involving both memory ("right brain" processing) and mental
>   construction ("left brain" processing). Subjects were asked a series
>   of questions in eight groupings. Each grouping of questions appealed
>   to a particular type of cognitive processing_visual, auditory,
>   kinesthetic, and emotional (visceral feelings). Each was also geared
>   to either memory (non-dominant hemisphere processing) or construction
>   (dominant hemisphere processing). Dilts' recordings tended to confirm
>   other tests which showed that lateralization of eye movements
>   accompanied brain activity during different cognitive tasks. This
>   pattern also seemed to hold for tasks requiring different senses. 
>   Looking upwards and the right can indicate imaginative construction of
>   a picture.

(snip)

> **Eyes Up and Right:** Dominant hemisphere visualization - i.e.,
>   constructed imagery and visual fantasy (Vc).

So my interpretation of my experience in terms of the above would be:

*When I imaginatively reconstruct my body as a mental image, my inner gaze is upwards and to the right.*

- *the **upwards** would explain why I visualise my feet **slightly forward of** my physical body*
- *the **to the right** would explain why I visualise my feet **rotated slightly clockwise** with respect to my physical body*

Does anyone have any views that would confirm this ?

Comment: Parietal lobe is generally responsible for the perception of the body space. There are some conditions in which people perceive their body spaces differently. Also read about phantom limbs.